# How to add a horizontal line in tables::tabular() output?

Tags: r, latex, tabular

I would like to add a horizontal line (using `Hline()`) in a moderately complex `tables::tabular()` output, when there are two factors on one side of the table.

Consider this:

```
require(tables)
require(car)
latex(
    tabular( (Factor(partner.status, "Status") +  1) 
         * (Factor(fcategory, "Authoritarianism") + 1)
         * ((Pct=Percent()))*Format(digits=1) 
         ~ 1, data=Moore) 
)
```

Which will yield:

```
\begin{tabular}{lllc}
\hline
Status & Authoritarianism &  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{All} \\ 
\hline
high & high & Pct  & $\phantom{0}16$ \\
 & low & Pct  & $\phantom{0}11$ \\
 & medium & Pct  & $\phantom{0}24$ \\
 & All & Pct  & $\phantom{0}51$ \\
low & high & Pct  & $\phantom{0}18$ \\
 & low & Pct  & $\phantom{0}22$ \\
 & medium & Pct  & $\phantom{00}9$ \\
 & All & Pct  & $\phantom{0}49$ \\
All & high & Pct  & $\phantom{0}33$ \\
 & low & Pct  & $\phantom{0}33$ \\
 & medium & Pct  & $\phantom{0}33$ \\
 & All & Pct  & $100$ \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

Which compiles (with the help of `\usepackage{booktabs}`) to:

[image]

In the output above, I would like to place a horizontal line after the 1st and the 2nd `All` fields from the `Authoritarianism` column (that is, a line before the `low` row and another line before the `All` row). Ho can I do that?

I tried to use `Hline()` as follows, but the resulting code isn't compilable by LaTeX:

```
latex(
    tabular( (Factor(partner.status, "Status") +  1) 
             * (Factor(fcategory, "Authoritarianism") + 1 + Hline())
             * ((Pct=Percent()))*Format(digits=1) 
             ~ 1, data=Moore) 
)
```

Comment: I share this question.